# Hadoop namenode format error

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to configure hadoop on ubuntu but when executing the command bin/hadoop namenode -format it shows the following message

> DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
>   Instead use the hdfs command for it,
>
> /home/sonali/hadoop-2.2.0/bin/hdfs: line 201:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/java: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

`line 201: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/java: No such file or directory`

The problem seems to be with Java. Try to **cd** to above path and then it will throw error as well(most probably).

So you need to set `JAVA_HOME` properly in your **.bashrc** file.

You can try setting **JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your JAVA_HOME in hadoop_base_dir/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh is right